# Copyright banner folding in sublime text (2 or 3 or any version)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a library of files which all display a lengthy license text at the top of each file. Is it possible to configure Sublime Text (2 or 3 or any version) to detect specific comment blocks, such as license text, and automatically fold them when those files are loaded or displayed?

So, turning:

```
//-*****************************************************************************
// Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Christopher Jon Horvath. All rights reserved.
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
//
// 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
// this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//
// 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
// this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
// and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
//
// 3. Neither the name of Christopher Jon Horvath nor the names of his
// contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this
// software without specific prior written permission.
// 
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
// AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
// IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
// ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
// CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
// SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
// INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
// CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
// ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
// POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
//-*****************************************************************************
```

into:

```
//-*****************************************************************************
// Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Christopher Jon Horvath. All rights reserved.
...
//-*****************************************************************************
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Also the pithy answer is yes; but I grabbed this from google's cache [http://tinyurl.com/mvvenlm
] If I understand correctly, anything between what the foldingStartMarker matches and what the foldingStopmarker matches will be folded (or to put it another way, fold arrows will appear at matches for the foldingStartMarker and collapse the code until the foldingStopMarker match)

Comment: I found the discussion you link to, which seems to conclude (at that time, 2009) that custom folding syntax was not supported, so the next thing I tried was to write this question!

Comment: Does Sublime Text 3 solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know (3 is still beta). But they're unlikely to fix it in 2. Sorry.

Comment: what kind of source code is it? JS? C?